# Module Not Found Error: No module named 'chart_studio'

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I run `!pip install chart_studio` in jupyter notebook.

Then when running this code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import cufflinks as cf
import chart_studio.plotly as py

from chart_studio.plotly import iplot

import plotly.graph_objects as go
chart_studio.tools.set_credentials_file(username=xx, api_key = xxx)
```

I get back:

`No module named 'chart_studio'`

I've tried syntax corrections but no joy.  Any suggestions?

Comment: when you run `!pip install chart_studio` in your notebook, does it go through or throws any error?

Answer (score 10):

Just `pip install chart_studio` in the current environment

Answer (score 4):

Use conda for the installation:

```
conda install -c plotly chart-studio
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it worked with:

```
pip install chart-studio
```

Answer (score 2):

```
!pip install chart_studio
```

if you are doing it on google colab

Answer (score 1):

```
import chart_studio.plotly as py
```

In the line above you have imported chart_studio as py. So,

```
chart_studio.tools.set_credentials_file(username=xx, api_key = xxx)
```

in this line you need call through the alias as

```
py.tools.set_credentials()
```

Else, you can just import chart_studio.plotly and use it directly.
Please comment if you have any doubts.

Comment: sorry, would you please explain in details? like where to get the username and api?

Answer (score 1):

The module chart_studio is no longer a module of the plotly package. You need to install chart-studio package

https://pypi.org/project/chart-studio/