# No module named chart_studio

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

I am a beginner and I have a problem

I take this error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chart_studio'

please help

```
! pip install Plotly
! pip install cufflinks
! pip install chart_studio
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import cufflinks as cf
import chart_studio.plotly as py 
import plotly.tools as tls
import plotly.graph_objs as go
```

Comment: format your code with four ```` above and below your code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're doing the following:

```
pip install chart-studio
```

and not

```
pip install chart_studio
```

Check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61233041/module-not-found-error-no-module-named-chart-studio), it might help you as well.

Comment: I tried both of them but nothing changed

Comment: I also checked that tread and tried all of the suggestions before but result is same